# Bookshelf.js : Avoid fetch call after call to save (update)

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

We are using bookshelf.js with MySQL.

We have a Table: **Contact**(`id, name, email_Id, updated_Contact_At`)

bookshelf Query :

```
new Contact({id: 1}).save(
    {name: 'Jhon Snow', email_Id: 'jhonsnow42@gmail.com', birthdate:'1998-10-21'},
    {patch: true, default: false, require: true, method: 'update'}
);
```

which translates to :

```
Update Contact set name = "Jhon Snow", 
email_Id = 'jhonsnow1212@gmail.com', 
birthdate = '1998-10-21', 
updated_Contact_At = 020-06-08T09:18:10.513Z 
where id = 1;
```

after executing above query bookshelf fetches the same record:

```
select Contact.* from Contact where Contact.id = 1 limit 1
```

Is there any way in *bookshelf.js* to stop fetch call after updating record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autoRefresh = false while updating record

```
new Contact({id: 1}).save(
    {name: 'Jhon Snow', email_Id: 'jhonsnow42@gmail.com', birthdate:'1998-10-21'},
    {patch: true, default: false, require: true, method: 'update', autoRefresh : false}
);
```

use Bookshelf.js **version: ^1.2.0**